# Excel Solver within another excel solver (series connection of solvers)

Tags: excel, optimization, excel-formula, mathematical-optimization, solver

I want to use the excel solver to solve a minimization problem and at the same time maximize another function again using the solver from excel. In other words I want to minimize a target function for a parameter *a* under the condition that another function is always maximized for the parameter *a*.

To be more precise imagine I want to minimize a function *f*  for the parameter *a*, i. e. I want the solver to find the value of *a* that minimizes *f*. But at the same time I want to maximize another function *g* for the parameter *x* that depends on *a* again using the excel solver (This is in principle the envelope theorem). This means I have the following problem:

min *f* for a

as well as

max *g* for  *x(a)*

This means that the excel solver should first use a value for *a* and find the value *x* that maximizes the function *g* given the value of *a*. This gives out a certain value for the function *f* under the restriction that we have a maximum for *g*. And then the solver should modify the value of *a* (for example with the Generalized gradient reduced method) and find again the value *x* that maximizes the function *g* given the value of the new *a*.

Is it possible to use the excel solver for two connected optimization problems (like in a series connection) where one solver is always part of the other solver?

Thank you.

edit: Pseudocode for VBA

```
SolverReset

SolverOk SetCell:="$G$4", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$I$8", Engine:=1 _
    , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverReset
SolverOK SetCell:="$G$5", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$I$9", Engine:=1 _
    , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
```

Comment: I think this is no programming question in the meaning of Stack Overflow but more a question for https://superuser.com

Comment: An optimization model inside an optimization model is called multi-level optimization (bilevel optimization if one inner and one outer optimization problem). These are very difficult problems. An optimization model with multiple objectives is called multi-objective or multi-criteria optimization. This is more common than multi-level optimization.

Comment: Thank you for the classification. Do you have any Idea how to run a multi-level optimization problem with excel?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is not possible with the excel solver. (I am not 100% sure). One approach I have seen is to write the inner optimization problem as a KKT system of equations. That would give you a standard single optimization problem.

Comment: Actually there is a workaround way to run a multi-level optimization problem with excel. For example: http://scholarbank.nus.edu.sg/handle/10635/89535

Comment: That is about a multi objective problem. Multi objective and multi level problems are very different animals. I see I am repeating myself.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Solver has only one objective cell.

But could you build your model to reflect the two calculations i.e. sum of A + 1/B for example?

Another possibility is to look at the extended solver offered by Frontline who provide the solver anyway.

Comment: I know that the solver has only one objective cell. I was thinking about a nested VBA code that looks somehow like the one I added to my post above.

Comment: But your code does them separately - my answer links them together... Which you use depends on what you finally want...

Comment: The code is supposed to do them separately. The second solver is supposed to maximize a given function for the values the first solver is giving out. Maybe it is helpful to think about it like this: I want to find the values that minimizes something under the constraint that something else is maximized.

Comment: Where you put in your question this AS WELL AS that hen that is not the linear situation you have just described in your comment - if you don’t make the question clear....

Answer (score 0):

There are definitions of the problem that either involve the same variable directly .. or not.  This matters!
Consider optimizing A - K*B where A is to be maximized and B is to be minimized and K is a weight to be determined.One likely has to experiment with setting the value of K.